# log4j unable to log float exponential notation

Tags: java

How to log float exponential notation using log4j.

```
float score = getScore(); //getScore() will return 3e-17
logger.debug("score is = {0}", score);
```

Above code logs score is = 0; Seems like its not liking value 3e-17

Any idea?

Comment: Format it yourself with `String.format()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be using MessageFormat formatting. Try using `"score is = {0,number,0.##E0}"` instead of just "{0}". Other options for the pattern (the "0.##E0" part) can be found in the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me :(